# What are these ugly red and blue thick lines when I \addplot+ in tikz beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to create an overlay plot in beamer so I am using the "overlay-beamer-styles" library. However my minimum working example turns out very unexpected:

[image]

Here is the code culprit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$\Pr(\theta=1)$},
        ylabel={$U$},
        xmin=-0.1, xmax=1.1,
        ymax=1.4,
        axis lines=middle,
        samples=100,
        height=0.8\textwidth,
        width =0.7\textwidth,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        xlabel style={anchor=west},
        ylabel style={anchor=east},
        clip=false,
        ]
        \visible<1->{
        \node[left] at (0,1) {$r_{00}$};
        \node[left] at (0,0.05) {$r_{10}$};
        \node[right] at (1,1) {$r_{11}$};
        \node[right] at (1,0.04) {$r_{01}$};}
        \addplot+[visible on=<2->,  domain=0:1] {x};
        \addplot+[visible on=<2->,  domain=0:1] {1 - x};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
  \end{frame}
```

I would like to know what happened.. Thank you very much!

Comment: Those look like marks to me. Set [`no markers`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-markers) if you don't want them. (They have nothing to do with beamer or overlays.)